# Appending to a text file in S3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto, boto3

I know how to write and read from a file in S3 using boto. I'm wondering if there is a way to append to a file without having to download the file and re-upload an edited version?

Comment: You can't append object store in S3. If it is small file (less than 512MB) ,  you can write  AWS lambda process to do the download, append and re-upload. So you don't need to use a EC2 server or download to a system outside AWS (which incur download charages per GB).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to append data to an existing object in S3.  You would have to grab the data locally, add the extra data, and then write it back to S3.